# Send list values to a textbox with Java script

Tags: javascript, html, list, textbox

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>title</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('li').click(function () {
                console.log($(this).text());
                $('#location').val($(this).text());
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    </body>
    <body>
        <div id="locationselect">
            <ul>
                <li>United Kingdom</li>
                <li>France</li>
                <li>Germany</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <input tpye="text" id="location" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this should work, given that I have around 10 days experience with html,4 with java script, I'm maybe not the best judge of such things. I'm retired and started a web developer coarse two weeks ago and i've already got great copying and pasting skills lol but I know this sounds old fashioned I'd like to understand why it doesn't work, if someone could help. Thankyou.

Comment: You have an extra *body* tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in [**document-ready handler**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Currently you're trying to bind events  on elements that don't yet exist.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        $('#location').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

### OR

Write you script at the bottom of page before you close *body* tag, like

```
<input tpye="text" id="location" />
<script>
    $('li').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
        $('#location').val($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ... or use event delegation

Comment: Thank you very much, I have so much to learn but I understood what you've told me lol. Very humbled that you took a moment out to help a complete stranger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind JQuery to HTML document ready event. This event is fired when browser load all page content and DOM is created

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('li').click(function () {
                        console.log($(this).text());
                        $('#location').val($(this).text());
                    });
                }
        );
    </script>
</head>
</body>
<body>
<div id="locationselect">
    <ul>
        <li>United Kingdom</li>
        <li>France</li>
        <li>Germany</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input tpye="text" id="location"/>
</body>
</html>
```

You can refer to http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for further details.

Comment: Thankyou very much, it's very humbling that a complete stranger would take the time and effort to answer my question. I've had a look at the link I get it, just about lol.